# The first variation formula

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I took this from Da Carmo (page 344),  not that is matters. I am going to use his curves and surface formula just to ensure the answer doesn't require any geometry answerers as I really feel this is analysis. If you would like he has the same proof in his Riemannian geometry book on page 196.

> A regular parametrized curve by arc length (so it is a geodesic?) $\alpha:[0,\ell] \to S$  is a geodesic $\iff$ for every proper variation $h: [0,\ell] \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to S$ of $\alpha$, $L'(0) = 0$
>
> Here $L'(0) = -\int_0^\ell \left < A(s),V(s) \right > ds$ with $V(s) = \partial h/\partial t (s,0)$ and $A(s) = (D/\partial s) \partial h/\partial s (s,0).$

Note that $L'(0)$ is the derivative of the energy function.

Okay my question lies in $\leftarrow$. Basically he says suppose $L'(0) = 0$, then we consider the variational field $V(s) = g(s)A(s)$. Why? I thought $V$ is supposed to be generic, why would we consider *only* forms of $V$ like that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that if for **any** proper variation $L'=0$ then the curve is a geodesic. Then, you can choose any particular variation and, if that suffices to prove that the curve is a geodesic, you are done.

A similar example: a sequence converges to $L$ iff all of its subsequences converge to $L$. Proof from right to left: Take the sequence itself.

Comment: If you choose a particular variation, then you haven't shown for every variation. You only show the particular one works. The analogy you gave isn't the same because the statement requires extracting the subsequence from the original one.

Comment: You do not have to show that $L'=0$ for every variation. You assume that. Then, you can use this information in any way you want to conclude that it is a geodesic. The way this information is used in this case is by using a particular variation. You know that $L'=0$ for that particular variation because you assume this to be the case for any variation.

Comment: $L'=0$ for any variation $\Longrightarrow$ $L'=0$ for some particular variation  $\Longrightarrow$ the curve is a geodesic.

Comment: I don't understand still, the question asks us to prove $L' = 0$ for every variation of $\alpha$. Not every variation vector field takes the form $f(s)A(s)$

Comment: The question is not asking that. You should prove that if for every variation you have $L'=0$ then the curve is a geodesic. You assume that $L'(0)=0$, you do not have to prove that. You have to use that knowledge to conclude that the curve is a geodesic.

Comment: so hang on, if $\mathscr{C}$ denotes the class of all such variations and if I pick a particular (sub)class like we are doing, say $\mathscr{S} \subset \mathscr{C}$, we have shown it is true for $\mathscr{S}$, but why are allowed to skip over $\mathscr{C} - \mathscr{S}$?

Comment: I thought you wanted to proof the implication $\Leftarrow$ that says: if $L'=0$ for all variations, then the curve is a geodesic". Is not that the case?

Comment: Yes, but if we get to choose our $V(s)$ like you said, why not just go with $V(s) = A(s)$?

Comment: To be able to conclude that you are at a minimum (geodesic) you have to make sure that derivatives "in many directions" are equal to zero. You need a whole family of deformations, parametrized by the scalar $f(s)$. Apparently, that is all you need to conclude that you are at a minimum in this case. I would be able to be more precise if you post the final part of the proof.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0oEYJ4S

Comment: It is just analysis actually, the rest. But I don't see the problem of letting $f = 1.$

Comment: You cannot choose $f=1$ since, by definition of an admissible variation, you should have $f(0)=f(l)=0$. But you can just fix some $f$ which is strictly positive on $(0,l)$ and then the relation $f(s)|A(s)|^2=0$ will force $A(s)=0$ for all $s\in[0,l]$ and therefore the curve is a geodesic.